# How can I add an AdBannerView to a UITabViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, iad

I have read through Apple's docs and referenced their infamous `iAdSuite` sample code. I have looked at many tutorials and stackoverflow posts and I still cannot arrive at the solution.

**How can I prevent iAd from being unloaded**, while being compliant with Apple's terms, while I am using a *tabviewcontroller*, and *storyboard*?

I have a `tabBarController` that splits into **3** separate `UINavigationControllers` with respective `UIViewControllers`.

Is there a way to add an `AdBannerView` to the `UITabBarController`? I have tried using a container view without success. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to provide a view controller with the AdBannerView and a contentViewController. Embed the TabBarController in the contentViewController and then adjust the views as needed.